# 837P mirth - I am trying to transform patient info when subscriber is not the patient along with some claims when subscriber is the patient

Tags: javascript, etl, edi, mirth, subscriber

I am trying to transform patient info when subscriber is not the patient along with some claims when subscriber is the patient.

I came across another challenge when subscriber is not the patient or subscriber has dependent. So far I tried below code and few other variations.

This code gives me all the subscribers for all claims and patient with qualifier QC. I do not need subscriber name TFirst6 when claim has dependent "QC_TFirst6". Sample message attached. Any advice is greatly appreciated. I tried deleting subscriber when subscriber is not the patient

Processed sample file

```
["TFirst1","TFirst2","TFirst3","TFirst4","TFirst5","TFirst6","QC_TFirst6","TFirst7","TFirst8","TFirst9","TFirst10","TFirst11","TFirst12","TFirst13","TFirst14","TFirst15"]
```

Expected results

```
["TFirst1","TFirst2","TFirst3","TFirst4","TFirst5","QC_TFirst6","TFirst7","TFirst8","TFirst9","TFirst10","TFirst11","TFirst12","TFirst13","TFirst14","TFirst15"]
```

```
var PatientFirstName = new Array();
var counter = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < msg['SBR'].length(); i++) {
  for each(nm1 in getSegmentsAfter(msg, msg['SBR'][i], 'NM1', true)) {
    //msgNM2 = (nm1['NM1.01']['NM1.01.1'].toString());
    if (nm1['NM1.01']['NM1.01.1'].toString() == 'QC') {
      PatientFirstName[counter] = (nm1['NM1.04']['NM1.04.1'].toString());
      counter += 1;
      channelMap.put("PatientFirstName",PatientFirstName);
    }
    else if (nm1['NM1.01']['NM1.01.1'].toString() == 'IL') {
      PatientFirstName[counter] = (nm1['NM1.04']['NM1.04.1'].toString());
      counter += 1;
      channelMap.put("PatientFirstName",PatientFirstName);
      logger.info("PatientFirstName is=: " + PatientFirstName); 
    }
  }
}
```